# extracting names from a jumbled up file

Tags: perl, awk, grep

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
MODIFIER|||c.72+1731G>T|SAMD11|protein_coding|CODING|NM_152486.2|2)
MODIFIER|||c.73-597G>A|SAMD11|protein_coding|CODING|NM_152486.2|2)
MODIFIER|||c.306-249T>C|SAMD11|protein_coding|CODING|NM_152486.2|4)
MODIFIER||2842||SAMD11|protein_coding|CODING|NM_152486.2|)
MODIFIER||4854||SAMD11|protein_coding|CODING|NM_152486.2|)
MODIFIER|||c.1443+808T>C|NOC2L|protein_coding|CODING|NM_015658.3|12)
LOW|||c.889C>G|NOC2L|protein_coding|CODING|NM_015658.3|8)
LOW|||c.889T>G|NOC2L|protein_coding|CODING|NM_015658.3|8)
MODIFIER||2687||KLHL17|protein_coding|CODING|NM_198317.2|)
MODIFIER||2885||NOC2L|protein_coding|CODING|NM_015658.3|)
```

I want to extract names like SAMD11, NOC2L, and KLHL17.

If these would have appeared in an accurate pattern, I would have split the file using tr as

`tr '|' '\t'` and after that would have extracted the column containing this name information.

Kindly help.

Thank you.

Comment: FYI, your file isn't "jumbled up" at all; it's simply pipe delimited, with some fields being empty.

Comment: Wrt `I would have..` - that would have been the wrong approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use awk,

```
$ awk -F\| '{print $5}' file
SAMD11
SAMD11
SAMD11
SAMD11
NOC2L
NOC2L
NOC2L
KLHL17
NOC2L
```

If you want to remove the duplicates then pass the awk output to `sort -u`,

```
$ awk -F\| '{print $5}' file | sort -u
KLHL17
NOC2L
SAMD11
```

As suggested by @jaypal, you could use the below awk one-liner command to remove the duplicates .

```
awk -F\| '!seen[$5]++ && $0=$5' file
```

Comment: Hi Avinash, Could you please suggest me a read. Where I can get good hold of all the tricks in bash.

Comment: @AvinashRaj For single command you can do `awk -F\| '!seen[$5]++ && $0=$5' file`

Comment: A classic: [Sed and Awk - O'Reily Media](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922259.do). Awk is a full programming language that assumes a file read loop. It can replace `grep`, `cut`, `tail`, `head`, etc.

Comment: I wouldn't get that sed and awk book as you don't need a book to learn what sed should be used for (simple subsitutions on a single line) and awk is better learned from the much more current Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition, by Arnold Robbins. To learn about bash, try Bash Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson.

Answer (score 6):

### Extract Fields Using the Standard *Cut* Command

Use the pipe symbol as a field separator, and extract the 5th field using the standard *cut* command. For example:

```
$ cut -d\| -f5 /tmp/corpus
SAMD11
SAMD11
SAMD11
SAMD11
SAMD11
NOC2L
NOC2L
NOC2L
KLHL17
NOC2L
```

Answer (score 5):

Like [Avinash Raj's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/avinash-raj) [awk solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25688418/725418), this can be done in Perl, exactly the same way. You can also include the same deduping process:

```
perl -F'\|' -lane'print $F[4] if !$seen{$F[4]}++;' yourfile.txt
```

- The `!$seen{$F[4]}++` statement returns true for any new keys in the `%seen` hash.
- The `-a` switch is autosplit, to which `-F` sets the delimiter (in form of a regex).
- `-l` handles newlines for the `print`, and
- `-n` puts the program code inside a `while (<>)` loop, which will read files or standard input.

Comment: I thought you were going to do `perl -F'\|' -lane '$seen{$F[4]}++ or print $F[4]' file` `:)`

Comment: No, that is what I would do. `;)` `$s{$_}++ or print for $F[4]`

Comment: @jaypal `unless $seen..` would perhaps be more intuitive, but I think it is good to use the idiomatic `!$seen{..}++` image.

Comment: Agree in general, but not necessarily for one-liners.

Answer (score 2):

Pure bash

```
declare -A seen
while IFS='|' read -r a b c d e f g
do
        let seen[$e]++
done <<'EOF'
MODIFIER|||c.72+1731G>T|SAMD11|protein_coding|CODING|NM_152486.2|2)
MODIFIER|||c.73-597G>A|SAMD11|protein_coding|CODING|NM_152486.2|2)
MODIFIER|||c.306-249T>C|SAMD11|protein_coding|CODING|NM_152486.2|4)
MODIFIER||2842||SAMD11|protein_coding|CODING|NM_152486.2|)
MODIFIER||4854||SAMD11|protein_coding|CODING|NM_152486.2|)
MODIFIER|||c.1443+808T>C|NOC2L|protein_coding|CODING|NM_015658.3|12)
LOW|||c.889C>G|NOC2L|protein_coding|CODING|NM_015658.3|8)
LOW|||c.889T>G|NOC2L|protein_coding|CODING|NM_015658.3|8)
MODIFIER||2687||KLHL17|protein_coding|CODING|NM_198317.2|)
MODIFIER||2885||NOC2L|protein_coding|CODING|NM_015658.3|)
EOF

printf "%s\n" "${!seen[@]}"
```

prints

```
NOC2L
KLHL17
SAMD11
```

or

```
while IFS='|' read -r a b c d e f g
do
        echo "$e"
done <$file | something
```

Comment: Nice, just FYI .. that it needs `bash` v4 for associative arrays.

Comment: @jaypal yay, thats true... the 1st thing on OS X is install `macports` and new a new `bash`...

Comment: True, I haven't used `macports` .. went with `homebrew` instead. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

### A Pure Bash One-Liner

If you don't want to use *cut* or *awk*, you can do the same think with Bash's [*read* builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html). Basically, this sets the input field separator to the pipe symbol, reads each line into an array named *line*; and then prints out the 5th field (because array indexes start at 0).

```
$ while IFS='|' read -a line; do echo "${line[4]}"; done < /tmp/foo
SAMD11
SAMD11
SAMD11
SAMD11
SAMD11
NOC2L
NOC2L
NOC2L
KLHL17
NOC2L
```